# Unable to inject jquery in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having issues with injecting jQuery into an iframe. With regular javascript it works as intended, but not with jQuery.

I have appended the jQuery CDN link to the iframes `<head>` and if I inspect the iframe element i can see it there. I can also see the scripts in the body tag after the function has run.

When executing the jquery script i get this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

If i add these I **don't** get the error but nothing happens.

```
$iframe[0].contentWindow.$ = $;
$iframe[0].contentWindow.jQuery = $;
```

I've tried to add timeouts to the append function to see if it was an issue with the CDN not loading quick enough. But no difference.

If i put the HTML and jQuery outside the iframe everything works as intended so I think there is something i've done wrong or missed regarding the iframe. Anyone have an idea what I could've done wrong here?

This is the function that injects the scripts

```
injectScript() {
    let $iframe = $('#iframe');
    $iframe.ready(function () {
      $iframe[0].contentWindow.$ = $;
      $iframe[0].contentWindow.jQuery = $;

      const jqueryScript = document.createElement("script");
      jqueryScript.type = "text/javascript";
      jqueryScript.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      $iframe.contents().find("head").append(jqueryScript);

      // This code works
      let vanilla = "<script>document.getElementById('vanilla').innerHTML = 'bar'<";
      vanilla += "/script>";
      $iframe.contents().find("body").append(vanilla);

      // This code works **not**
      let jQuery = "<script>$('#jquery').text('foo')<";
      jQuery += "/script>";
      $iframe.contents().find("body").append(jQuery);

    })
  }
```

the html in the iframe

```
 <div id="jquery">foo</div>
 <div id="vanilla">foo</div>
```

Comment: You cannot access the dom of the iframe unless it is from the same domain as your current site, for obvious security reasons

Comment: Yes, but they are on the same domain? How can i check that? And how come it works with regular JS but not the jQuery then?

Comment: Instead of injecting why don't you just add the script into the html of the iframe?

Comment: Its a case where we want to display modules/components in different sizes after the user has interacted with the iframe. The components depends on jquery for animations and other stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Why not just include the jquery in the iframe html before hand, and then handle interaction and animation from within the iframe's javascript

Comment: `$iframe[0].contentWindow.$ = $; $iframe[0].contentWindow.jQuery = $;` attempts to add references to the parent window's jQuery instance to the iframe's window. That's a bad idea. And redundant, since you immediately load the jQuery script, which should be creating its own references to those same variables when evaluated.